# Сравнения массивов, нахождение отсутствующих элементов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, немного тупой вопрос, но ка кто не могу допетрить..

есть два массива, сравниваем их друг с другом

```
  foreach($answer_arr as $k=>$value){
        $tmp=$answer_arr[$k];
        if($tmp==$real_answ[$k]){
                $right_answer++; 
  }
```

фишка в том, что   $answer_arr  может содержать меньшее кол-во значений чем $right_answer
 как бы отловить количество этих пропусков...

Answer (score 2):

Массивы в каком формате? Если массивы одномерные то перед сравнением запускайте в теле цикла тот который больше.

```
$c1 = count($answer_arr);
$c2 = count($real_answ);
if($c1 > $c2){
// код проверки
}
else{
// код проверки
};
```

Также проверяйте существование индекса в массивах функцией array_key_exists()

Comment: Осмыслил!) спасибо. да . действительно затупил))